# Express (1,...,n) as a product of 2-cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

In Alan F. Beardon's "Algebra and geometry" he asks in an exercise to express $(1\ \ldots\ n)$ as a product of two cycles:

> Show that $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)=(1\ 4)(1\ 3)(1\ 2)$. Express $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)$ as a product of $2$-cycles. Express $(1\ 2\ \ldots\ n)$ as a product of $2$-cycles.

I assume that if we are working with the set of numbers $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ doing so is not possible. Since all of the numbers of the set will be part of the cycle $(1\ \ldots\ n)$ already. I am new in this subject, so I do not know if I am making a mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Note that it doesn't have to be two _disjoint_ cycles.

Comment: aaaaah! Great, thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is not asking for a product of $2$-cycles? Either is possible, but the latter would be more generalizable.

Comment: You were precisely right @TobiasKildetoft. But how would you do it?

Comment: The problem was stated the way it was in order to helpfully guide you away from tackling the hardest part right away. Did you work out how $(1 2 3 4) = (1 4)(1 3)(1 2)$? Did you try to do a similar thing with $(1 2 3 4 5)$? What happened then?

Comment: (12345) = (12) (13) (14) (15) according to my thinking, I'm working on the (1 2 3 ... n) I suppose that (12) (13) ... (1n) @DavidK

Comment: That's good progress. I recommend to edit the question to add those observations and ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Because $(1\ n)(1\ n)$ is the identity, the $n$-cycle $(1\ 2\ \ldots\ n)$ is the product of the two cycles $(1\ n)$ and
$$(1\ n)(1\ 2\ \ldots\ n)=(1\ 2\ \ldots\ n-1).$$
Induction on $n$ now also shows that $(1\ 2\ \ldots\ n)$ is a product of $2$-cycles.

Comment: What I've been seeing is that actually any cycle can be decomposed into a product of 2-cycles. For example, if I take (3 7 5 8 ) then, it would be equal to (3 8) (3 5) (3 7). So I will always have to fix some number within the cycle and then cyclically put in the second part of the parenthesis the next one in the cycle until I finish. Is that correct? What would be the general notation?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. A proof of this is given by a minor variation on my answer; in stead of the $n$-cycle, apply the same argument to any cycle $(k_1\ k_2\ \ldots\ k_n)$ with the $2$-cycle $(k_1\ k_n)$. You will find that
$$(k_1\ k_2\ \ldots\ k_n)=(k_1\ k_n)(k_1\ k_{n-1})\cdots(k_1\ k_2).$$